# html5 in mobile view have a border ,but don't have in pc view

Tags: css, html

I add `background` in my div ,but in the pc there is no border, in the phone there is a border. I think it should not have borders;

The code list:

```html
<div style="
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 100px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  margin: 100px;
">
```

the pc view:

[image]

the phone view:

[image]

Is that where I wrote the wrong thing? Thanks everyone.

Comment: very strange, but i notice is that this border is coming from the background, update the color and you see it too

Comment: The border has a border... Interesting. What about on real mobiles? Or other browser's mobile view?

Comment: No, i tested your code on `iphone` and it's ok, it just show on browser mobile view (chrome), it just a browser bug.

Comment: yes i think it's only a Chrome bug for mobile view.

Comment: But after all, there is one question, why you used 100px border in white color? sounds like you want to add some margin with border.

Comment: Yes, I want to separate the border  and the background. @Mr.x

Comment: I view the html in the andirod device . It also this

Comment: @devkang separate with white color? okay, increase your margin, and remove 100px border. over.

Comment: I believe it's a chrome bug, but nothing you can do now, just solve your problem with above comment, with alternate way.

Comment: Thansk! But it appear in andriod brower. The andriod brower is also the chrome?

Comment: @devkang of course not, But maybe it use `-webkit-`

Answer (score 1):

Here i give you code that add border in both view mobile as well as Desktop based on your requirement

```
<div style="
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 100px;
">
</div>
```

*** this is based on your code so this will show you border in all devices

Answer (score -2):

Please give border color any other then white

i can see in pc and mobile both...

or if you want your border white then choose  your body color different then white.

Comment: sorry, I don't set border. I want to remove border in phone view. And , can you see border in pc ?

Comment: You don't set border but it caused by this => `border: 100px solid #fff;` @devkang

Comment: @Mr.x by border he meant the strange one that appears on mobile in addition to the one already set (that is not the issue)

Comment: I know @TemaniAfif i saw that border in mobile view, i mean, it cause by this border.

Comment: you have to use media queries for that  :-)

Comment: @Mr.x how it's caused by this border ? i didn't get you

Comment: @TemaniAfif OP set `border: 100px solid #fff;` right? in desktop view it's ok and we don't see any extra border, but in mobile view it show a border, it caused by that 100px border, I wanna say it's a browser bug.

Answer (score -2):

Please remove the border from your inline style insted.